# When can $0^0=0$?

Tags: limits, graphing-functions, limits-without-lhopital

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/plmfyiyutt) I can see that $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^x=1$$

if it is the case that $0^0$ is undefined except through limits what would an example be of an equation where the limit is $0$ or another value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples ... all limits are as $x \to +\infty$
\begin{align}
u &= e^{-x} \qquad v=  \frac{1}{x^2}\;  \qquad \lim u =0
 \qquad \lim v =0 \qquad \lim u^v = 1
\\
u &= e^{-x} \qquad v=  \frac{1}{x}\;  \qquad \lim u =0
 \qquad \lim v =0 \qquad \lim u^v = e^{-1}
\\
u &= e^{-x} \qquad v=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}  \qquad \lim u =0
 \qquad \lim v =0 \qquad \lim u^v = 0
\\
u &= e^{-x} \qquad v=  \frac{a}{x}\;  \qquad \lim u =0
 \qquad \lim v =0 \qquad \lim u^v = e^{-a}
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=0$, $g(x)=\vert x\vert$. Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)^{g(x)}=0$ (since for all $a\not=0$ we have $f(a)^{g(a)}=0$).

Answer (score 0):

See two examples page 9 in the paper : "Zero to the zero-th power" https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power .
In one example, the limit is $e^2$. In the other example, the limit is $e^{-1}$. One can find as many examples as wanted with different values of limit.